# How to specify a unicode character using QString?

Tags: qt, unicode, qstring

How can I specify a unicode character by code (such as "4FF0") using QString? I tried `QString s("\u4FF0");` but it only outputs a question mark. Any idea how to do this?

**Edit:**

It works that way, but is there a more direct way?

```
std::wstring str = L"\u4FF07";
QString s = QString::fromStdWString(str));
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If by direct you mean using a Unicode code point value, then [`QChar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html) may be it:

```
QString s = QChar(0x4FF0);
```

Answer (score 17):

Apparently '\u' only works with UTF-8:

```
QString s = QString::fromUtf8("\u4FF0");

// Or with that at the start of your main function:
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
...
QString s("\u4FF0");
```

Comment: Does standard C++ even support \u?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, it does since at least C++98.

Answer (score 6):

Since C++11 you can use UTF-8 string literal prefix (`u8`):

```
QString s(u8"\u4FF0");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a direct pointer, try QString(QChar(0x4FF0));

You need to ensure you have the correct utf-16 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

`QChar`s are limited to 16 bits, so they cannot represent numbers above `0xffff`. From the Qt docs (6.2):

> The QChar class provides a 16-bit Unicode character.

Trying to store a larger value in a `QChar` will trigger an assertion error: `ASSERT: rc <= 0xffff`.

But Unicode needs more space. The Unicode standard 15.1 already defines 149,641 characters, [too much for 16 bits](https://www.unicode.org/versions/stats/charcountv15_1.html). So a `QChar` cannot be used to store an arbitrary Unicode character.